# Kivy: creating a pan screen effect?

Tags: python, api, scrollview, kivy

I am an experienced python programmer but the problem with Kivy's documentation is not only does it go all over the place for Kivy beginners, it doesn't have simple, complete, working code examples as it explains the APIs.

I used my own wits and discovered how to create a sprite, center the graphics/texture origin/axis, animate the sprite, move it around and create a background.

For my next practice session, I wanted to make the screen pan/scroll, all why staying centered focus on my sprite.

Again, there really isn't working code in Kivy's ScrollView doc.

Can anyone provide me with the simplest form of working code that achieves what I'm looking for?

Again, keep it simple because I'm just trying to see how the functions/methods are used in code.

--------update--------------

Whoot!!!!  Did it...and no scrollbars!  There's one more issue to work out and that is the choppy screen movement.  I'm not fearing that because I believe it's related to the choppy movement of my sprite.

My theory is, when I changed movement over to Clock Interval control combined with smooth animation movement...that choppiness will go away.  If my theory is correct, I will post the code.  Otherwise, I don't think anyone will be interested in broken code, lol.

I'll do it tomorrow; tired right now because I've been at Kivy all day and the girl has one tough "beaver."  PS...I see Kivy 1.9.1 will have a Scoll_To(widget) call.

---------update 4:00 am----------

I saw a quick fix before bed and now the choppy movement is gone.  Whoot!!!!  Kicking Kivy's butt!  Um...er...don't hurt me kivy...  Lol.

Right now I'm just trying to learn how to code all the basic logic needed for game design, Kivy style.

So now I can create a game world, set a background, create an Actor, move that actor by keyboard (so far), animate the actor and now pan the view perfectly.

Tomorrow (technIcally,today) I will post the code as an answer to the question....hopefully I remember.

Comment: For a good and quite complete introduction to kivy, the tutorial series done by @inclement are very helpful IMO : http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/   And you've got in particular a section about scrollable label (or other thing...) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdcUg_rX2fM

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of examples for kivy [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples). You can check the [scrollview example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.py):

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.8')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class ScrollViewApp(App):

    def build(self):

        # create a default grid layout with custom width/height
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10,
                size_hint=(None, None), width=500)

        # when we add children to the grid layout, its size doesn't change at
        # all. we need to ensure that the height will be the minimum required to
        # contain all the childs. (otherwise, we'll child outside the bounding
        # box of the childs)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        # add button into that grid
        for i in range(30):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(480, 40),
                         size_hint=(None, None))
            layout.add_widget(btn)

        # create a scroll view, with a size < size of the grid
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(500, 320),
                pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)
        root.add_widget(layout)

        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Comment: I actually followed the scrollview example and got the error, "invalid property - minimum_height."  Could have something to do with the fact I have a background class and a sprite class.  The gameworld class adds everything to it.  I guess I'm trying to use a basic setup logic that works with some game engines but obviously with Kivy, it's not going to be that easy.

Comment: @Cotownsend78, update your question and add your code and the error you get

Answer (score -1):

Since I solved the problem, I gained a better understanding of what's going on.  Setting the ScrollView in Kivy is equivalent to setting the ViewPort in some game engines.

With that said, the GameWorld itself really is the GameWindow, since the "View" is applied to it.

Oh...the scrollbars do still show...they are just so hard to see.  I'm not worrying about hiding those right now.

Today I think I'll write code which handles keys pressed at the same time.  I like giving 2D Actors an 8 directional movement.

After that, I'll write some collision detection code and from that, I'll write 2D depth code based on the "y-" theory.

```
class Actor(Widget):
...
class Background(Widget):
...

class GWindow(Widget):
...
    self.size_hint = (None,None)

class TestApp(App):
    def Build(self):
        self.GW = GWindow
        self.SV = ScrollView(size_hint=(None,None), size=(800,600))
        self.SV.add_widget(self.GW)
        return self.SV
```